# Why Rebol Copy Big File fails with really big files whereas windows explorer doesn't?

Tags: rebol

I tried carl function
http://www.rebol.com/article/0281.html

with 155 Mo it works.

Then I tested with 7 Go it fails without saying the limit.

Why is there a limit I can't see anything in code that puts a limit.

There's no error message

```
>> copy-file to-rebol-file "D:\@mirror_ftp\cpmove.tar" to-rebol-file "D:\@mirror_ftp\testcopy.tar"
0:00
== none
>>
```

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you were to show what console output was produced.

Comment: I agree but there was no error message as I have added above :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

REBOL uses 32-bit signed integers, so it can't read files bigger than 2147483647 bytes (2^31-1) which is roughly 2GB. REBOL3 uses 64-bit integers, so won't have such limitation.

Comment: Is this going to be an issue with Red too?